# Is it possible to use environment variable to replace tf.constant in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and recently I am working with a project has the following code

```py
    def build_fv_graph(self) -> tf.Tensor:
        with tf.variable_scope("modifier_attr"):
            t_mdl_name = tf.constant(self.model_name, name="mdl_name", dtype=tf.string)
```

As you can see, the code here use `tf.constant` to hard code a string into the model, which would be convenient to allow user to override it, for example, via an environment variable. My question is it possible, or is there better solution for such use case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if this will work for you. But let's try.
Load your model with something like this:

```
def load_pb(path_to_pb):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path_to_pb, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        return graph
```

When creating model use something like this:

```
# Create a placeholder for mdl_name
mdl_name_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name="mdl_name")

# Create the graph
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    with tf.variable_scope("modifier_attr"):
        # Use a placeholder instead of a constant
        t_mdl_name = tf.identity(mdl_name_placeholder, name="mdl_name_identity")
        
    # Add your logic for constructing the graph
```

When you want to change variable, use something like this:

```
# Example usage:
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    # Initialize variables (if you have any in the graph)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Feed the placeholder with the desired value
    mdl_name_value = "xyz"
    
    # Run the graph with a new value for mdl_name
    result = sess.run(t_mdl_name, feed_dict={mdl_name_placeholder: mdl_name_value})
    print(result)
```

That's what I can come up with knowing details you provided. Maybe some of the syntax is not right, but the idea is here.

Comment: I am not to change it at the time of building model, but at the time of using model.

Comment: I edited answer. I'm still not sure if that's what you want. If not, please describe to me how you would like to use it.

Comment: For example, if I build a model named `model.pb`  and set `mdl_name` to `abc`, then send it to another user . Is it possbile for the user to change the value, for example `xyz`?

Comment: How do you want to send it? Save model to file using tensorflow api?

Comment: Save it as file. Actually I am working on other people's code base, so I am not sure if I am working on the right direction.

Comment: I edited answer. I'm not expert for tensorflow so let me know if this is closer to what you need.